# Delete runs of certain value before and after specific value

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I have a data frame with several columns. Based on the column 'activity', I want to remove entire contiguous runs of a specific value, 'pt', but only when they occur immediately before or after a run of 'outside'.

In the simplified data below, there is one run where 'activity' is 'outside', and which have chunks of 'pt' before and after. These two 'pt' chunks should be removed.

```
   activity dist
1      home    1
2        pt    2 # <- run of 'pt' before run of 'outside': remove
3        pt    3 # <-
4        pt    4 # <- 
5   outside    5
6   outside    6
7        pt    7 # <- run of 'pt' after run of 'outside': remove
8        pt    8 # <-
9      work    9
10       pt   10
11       pt   11
12     home   12
```

Thus, the desired output is:

```
    activity dist 
 1      home    1 
 2   outside    5 
 3   outside    6 
 4      work    9 
 5        pt   10 
 6        pt   11 
 7      home   12
```

How can this be achieved?

---

`dput` of data:

```
structure(list(activity = c("home", "pt", "pt", "pt", "outside", "outside", "pt", "pt", "work", "pt", "pt", "home"),
              dist = 1:12),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: it looks like you just dropped all entries in which `activity_type=="pt interaction"`?

Comment: no, I'm sorry  for not specifying enough. There are also occasions where "pt interaction" appears before or after, as example, "home". Therefore, these "pt interaction" I want to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use some convenience functions from `data.table` package: `rleid` to "[g]enerate run-length type group id", and `shift` to get the values before and after the focal index in a vector.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[ , r := rleid(activity)]

d[!(r %in% r[activity == "pt" & shift(activity, type = "lead") == "outside" |
               shift(activity) == "outside" & activity == "pt"])]

#    activity dist r
# 1:     home    1 1
# 2:  outside    5 3
# 3:  outside    6 3
# 4:     work    9 5
# 5:       pt   10 6
# 6:       pt   11 6
# 7:     home   12 7
```

---

#### Explanation:

Coerce your `data.frame` to a `data.table` (`setDT(d)`). Create run length index of 'activity' (`rleid`). Check if current value is 'pt' and next value is 'outside' (`activity == "pt" & shift(activity, type = "lead") == "outside"`), or (`|`) if current value is 'pt' and previous value is 'outside' (`activity == "pt" & shift(activity) == "outside"`).

Where this condition is `TRUE`, grab the run groups to be removed (`r[<condition>]`). Check if run are in the groups to be removed (`r %in% <run groups to be removed>`). If so, do not (`!`) keep these rows when indexing the data (`d[<condition>]`)

---

#### `base` alternative using `rle`.

The values of runs of 'pt' before or after 'outside' are replaced with `NA`. The rle is converted back to a vector (`inverse.rle`) and rows with `NA` are removed (`na.omit`).

Obviously, if there are rows with `NA` in the original data set which you want to keep, you need to use another value for replacement.

```
with(rle(d$activity),
     values[c(which(head(values, -1) == "pt" & tail(values, -1) == "outside"),
              which(head(values, -1) == "outside" & tail(values, -1) == "pt") + 1)]) <- NA

d$activity = inverse.rle(r)
na.omit(d)
```

Comment: my god, thank you very much @Henrik! Do you mean with minimal examples the minimal desired output or the data to play with? I agree, I've struggled to formulate my problem but I thought I've provided enough data:) please let me know what was lacking to improve my next question.

Comment: You are welcome. "_Do you mean with minimal examples the minimal desired output or the data to play with?_". Both. Try to reduce the toy data to a bare minimum, but still having sufficient complexity to demonstrate your issue. Not more, not less. Then show the desired result _given_ this data. The data in top of your post is small and nice, but it is not in a format which is easily copy-pasteable for anyone trying to help you (try e.g. the "standard method" to read it (`read.table(text = "<paste-your-data-here>", header = TRUE")`). Then I had a look at you `dput`, which is a very good format..

Comment: ...however, it's _much_ bigger (100 rows) than what is needed to demonstrate your problem. So I ended up making my own toy data, which apparently seemed to be of sufficient complexity ;) Thanks and good luck!

Comment: And regaring "_struggled to formulate my problem_", I may suggest an edit on your question with some 'keywords' which hopefully could make your post more searchable and useful also for future visitors.